# "A backoff operation is already in progress" - Firebase admin SDK Electron

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, electron

When I try to read create/read/update anything in my Firestore I get a very vague error

[image]

The code I am trying to excecute is as follow:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import serviceAccount from '../../firebase/woonstee-crm-firebase-adminsdk-vqc2y-3996fc5471.json'

const account = serviceAccount as admin.ServiceAccount;

const app = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(account),
  databaseURL: `https://${serviceAccount.project_id}.firebaseio.com`,
});

const firestore = app.firestore();
const customer = firestore.collection('customers').doc('9pCM5W30Fyw0o8ypYdgF');

(() => {
  console.log(customer.get().then(doc => console.log(doc)))
})()
```

What does this error mean? All I could find was

[image]

The message is so unclear that I have no idea what is causing this error. I have looked up if I have reached my quota of the day/month, which isn't the case. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245237/error-a-backoff-operation-is-already-in-progress-when-i-try-to-read-data-from-f)?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, as I said, I did not reach any quota. The answer given there is not helpfull.

Comment: I'm not sure how can I replicate this issue but do you know which line exactly is throwing this error?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, `customer.get().then(doc => console.log(doc))` is throwing the error.

Comment: Nvm but have you tried running that outside of that anonymous function?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, I did. Still throws the same error.

Comment: A backoff operation is a type of throttling when you are trying to make some request that is resulting in an error. As an example (these timings don't match Firestore's exactly), if the first request fails, you make wait 1s and then try again. If that also fails, you try again after 2s, then after 5s, then after 20s, then after 60s, and so on until you hit some predefined limit.

Comment: To help find the cause, you can activate Firestore's debug logger using `app.firestore().setLogFunction(console.log.bind(null))`.